# Elastic search multi condition query

Tags: elasticsearch

i am new to elastic search and trying to query my stored log with the following conditions:
return all "fatal" level fields from the last hour.
This is the last code i run that returns an error:

```
    GET /eu-multitenant*/_search
{
  "query": 
  { "bool": {
    "should": [
        "match": {"level": "fatal" },
        "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-1h"}}
      ]
  }

  },
  "_source": ["d.Message","@timestamp"],
  "sort": { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "desc"}},
  "size": 100
}
```

This is the error:

```
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "json_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@4be698a; line: 5, column: 17]"
      }
    ],
```

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got some inspiration from posting the question and located my error.
I did not surround the different query conditions with { }.

```
GET /eu-multitenant*/_search
{
  "query": 
  { "bool": {
    "must": [
        {"match": {"level": "fatal" }},
        {"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-24h"}}}
      ]
  }

  },
  "_source": ["d.Message","@timestamp"],
  "sort": { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "desc"}},
  "size": 100
}
```